# Neo4J bulk create relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

***Is CSV the only options to speed up my bulk relationships creation?***

I read many articles in internet, and they all are telling about CSV. CSV will definitely give me a performance boost (*could you suppose how big?*), but I'm not sure I can store data in CSV format. *Any other options? How much I will get from using Neo4J 3 BOLT protocol?*

### My program

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.7.  I try to create about 50000 relationships at once. I execute queries in batch of size 10000, and it takes about ***120-140 seconds*** to insert all 50000.

My query looks like:

```
MATCH (n),(m) 
WHERE id(n)=5948 and id(m)=8114 
CREATE (n)-[r:MY_REL {
    ID:"4611686018427387904",
    TYPE: "MY_REL_1"
    PROPERTY_1:"some_data_1",
    PROPERTY_2:"some_data_2",
    .........................
    PROPERTY_14:"some_data_14"
}]->(m) 
RETURN id(n),id(m),r
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is written in the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/):

> Cypher supports querying with parameters. This means developers don’t
>   have to resort to string building to create a query. In addition to
>   that, it also makes caching of execution plans much easier for Cypher.

So, you need pack your data as parameters and pass with cypher query:

```
UNWIND {rows} as row
MATCH (n),(m) 
WHERE id(n)=row.nid and id(m)=row.mid
CREATE (n)-[r:MY_REL {
    ID:row.relId,
    TYPE:row.relType,
    PROPERTY_1:row.someData_1,
    PROPERTY_2:row.someData_2,
    .........................
    PROPERTY_14:row.someData_14
}]->(m) 
RETURN id(n),id(m),r
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm gonna test performance with this solution, will let you know in few hours

Comment: @By the way, if you use the embedded server, why do you want the cypher? Why not use java-way: `graphDb.findNodes` etc? http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-new-index

Comment: we gonna use bolt protocol

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk By the way, if you need a batch creation of the relationship, I do not advise you to return anything. Or at least return the number of created relationships - `return count(r)`.